# How can I detect if dependencies have changed prior to a build event in VS2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a pre-build event in VS2010 which obfuscates some code.  However, it runs every time I try to build the executable regardless of whether the dependencies have chanced.  How can I detect if it really needs to be run?

Comment: msdn says: "Pre-build events do not run if the project is up to date and no build is triggered." : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4(v=vs.80).aspx . If you need to do more complex dependency checking one way is to call a .bat file.

Answer (score 1):

I would look for solutions involving msbuild. Try editing the csproj file and tweak the commented out section dealing with <Target Name="BeforeBuild"> section.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171462(v=vs.90).aspx

---

**Dependency Analysis**

In more advanced scenarios targets can describe relationships between each other and perform dependency analysis, which allows whole sections of the build process to be skipped if that target is up-to-date. You can declare the targets that must run before a specific target by using the **DependsOnTargets** attribute. When a target is run, the MSBuild engine will automatically run any targets listed in this attribute first. For more information, see How to: Build Incrementally.

[How to: Build Incrementally](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171483%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)